# Refactoring JavaScript code in regard to a lot of DOM methods

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I'm a beginner in JavaScript, and i'm writing a simple To-do list application. That accepts user input and adds it as a task in a form of a `checkbox`.

The problem is that, the code has become more and more repetitive, I tried to make functions for the most repeating parts. But i feel that there's a better way to do that using some kind of DOM native functions.

Here's my code (i'm writing a comment where i feel that there're better choice to make):

```
window.onload = function(){
    submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){ 

         //Some code ...                

        var task = document.createElement("input"); 
        task.id = "task" + i;
        task.type = "checkbox"; 

        var taskLabel = document.createElement("label"); 
        taskLabel.htmlFor = "task" + i;
        taskLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textBox.value));

         //This is from a function i've created to create buttons
        var deleteBtn = createButton("delete");
        var undoBtn = createButton("undo", "none");
        var divideBtn = createButton("divide");

        var taskContainer = document.createElement("p"); 

        //A LOT of appendChild is happening .. How can i minimize that using 
        //native DOM methods
        taskContainer.appendChild(task); 
        taskContainer.appendChild(taskLabel);
        taskContainer.appendChild(deleteBtn);
        taskContainer.appendChild(divideBtn);
        taskContainer.appendChild(undoBtn);

        taskPool.appendChild(taskContainer);        

         //the rest of the code ....



    }); 


}
```

Comment: All the nodes that you create need to be appended to the DOM at some point, so if you're looking to reduce the number of lines of code, you don't have much options AFAIK except stick 'em in an array and use a loop. If you're looking to get the best possible performance (not LoC), you can add all nodes to a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/DocumentFragment) that's not attached to the visible DOM and then attach all that to the on-screen DOM in one call, but if you're adding just tens of nodes in total that's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: If you use jquery, you can write shorter expressions, for instance, var taskContaner = $('<p/>'); or var task = $('<input type="textbox"/>').attr('id', 'task' + i);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to minimize your code wherever you can then using a library like jquery would be one of your best options.

However, if in this case you'd prefer to stick to 'pure' javascript, you could avoid all the appends up there, by adding a method to the Node object of the DOM similar to this one:

```
/* is Node.prototype.multiAppend already defined? */
if( typeof Node.prototype.multiAppend !== "function" ) {
    Node.prototype.multiAppend = (function() {
        /*get the Array.prototype.slice method to use on the returned function*/
        var slice = [].slice;

        /*the function multiAppend comes to be*/
        return function() {
            var i = 0,
                max = arguments.length;

            for (; i < max; i++) {
                this.appendChild(arguments[i]);
            }

            /*allow chainability*/
            return this;
        };
    })();
}
```

This would allow you to do something like this:

```
var item = document.getElementsByClassName('item')[0],

    /*create elements*/
    h1 = document.createElement("h1"),
    div = document.createElement("div"),
    p = document.createElement("p");

    /*append them to item with just one line*/
    item.multiAppend(h1, div, p)​​​;​​​​​
```

**Take a look at the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/8mjBR/2/ ***

Comment: mmmm, thanks a lot. I was thinking of something like that. But is extending the prototype of an object like Node, Array or Math for example, is a good practice?

Comment: I probably should leave that question for someone more experienced. I have however found an article by Juriy Zaytsev, that talks just about this - http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/ . Apparently, even though this (extending the DOM) is a solution used by big libraries like Mootools and PrototypeJS, it's a very risky one.

Comment: It seems to be a great article, i'm bookmarking it. Thanks :)

Comment: Np. Having read the same article until the end, I've realized,  PrototypeJS doesn't work by extending the DOM anymore. As for Mootools, I do not know. Probably not. Anyway, just wanted to clarify that, and point out my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

This is the reason most people use jQuery and template systems like Handlebars or Mustache. It's actually a lot faster, not to mention cleaner to implement and thus easier to maintain, to simply insert your complete view block into the DOM instead of manually creating the individual DOM elements and appending them one by one.

The recommended way to manipulate the DOM using jQuery is to do something like:

```
var taskName = 'task'+i,
    taskLabel = textBox.value,
    taskHtml =
        '<div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="'+taskName+'">
            <label for="'+taskNAme+'">'+taskLabel+'</label>
            <fieldset>
                <button id="btnDel'+i+'">Delete</button>
                <button id="btnDiv'+i+'">Divide</button>
                <button id="btnUndo'+i+'">Undo</button>
            </fieldset>
        </div>';
$(taskHtml).appendTo('#TaskPool');
```

Creating large DOM constructs in a single go through `innerHTML` is a lot faster than manually creating and appending the individual elements.

However, this still requires mixing HTML and JS, which is pretty ugly. So that's why these days developers opt for templates, which allow you to do something like:

```
<script id="task-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="task{{i}}">
        <label for="task{{i}}">{{label}}</label>
        <fieldset>
            <button id="btnDel{{i}}">Delete</button>
            <button id="btnDiv{{i}}">Divide</button>
            <button id="btnUndo{{i}}">Undo</button>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</script>
```

Then in your click handler:

```
var source = $("#task-template").html(),
    template = Handlebars.compile(source),
    context = {
      i: i,
      label: textBox.value
    },
    html = template(context);
$('#TaskPool').append(html);
```

And from there, you can take it one step further and add two-way data binding, such as through Angular.js, Kockout.js or jsViews (+ jsRender). Then you just have something like this:

```
<ol id="TasksList">
    <li ng-repeat="task in tasks | orderBy:orderProp">
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{task.name}}" ng:model="task.checked">
        <label for="{{task.name}}">{{task.label}}</label>
        <fieldset>
            <button ng-click="deleteTask(task.id)">Delete</button>
            <button ng-click="divideTask(task.id)">Divide</button>
            <button ng-click="undoTask(task.id)">Undo</button>
        </fieldset>
    </li>            
</ol>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.orderProp = 'id';
$scope.nextId = 0;
$scope.addTask = function(label) {
    var id = $scope.nextId++,
        task = {
            id: id,
            label: label,
            name: 'task'+id,
            checked: false
        };
    $scope.tasks.push(task);
};
$scope.deleteTask = function(id) { ... };
$scope.divideTask = function(id) { ... };
$scope.undoTask = function(id) { ... };
```

Comment: Wow, this is a lot of frameworks and template stuff. And it looks really interesting, what do you advice me to do ? learn jQuery and templates after learning JavaScript ?

Comment: @Rafael: I think you probably already grasp JS well enough that you could start learning/experimenting with popular utility/DOM-manipulation libraries and MVC/template/data-binding frameworks while you continue to learn JS. And this way you can dive into the code behind jQuery and other libraries and see how other developers solve common problems.